# TSQL - Split GUID/UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Case: We have smart guids in a table and need to extract 2nd and 4th parts out of it. I was thinking about writing a function that can take in @partnumber and return the extracted value for it.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'A7DDAA60-C33A-4D7A-A2D8-ABF20127C9AE'
```

> 1st part = A7DDAA60, 2nd part = C33A, 3rd part = 4D7A, 4th part =
> A2D8, and 5th part = ABF20127C9AE

Based on the @partnumber, it would return one of those values.

I'm trying to figure out how to split it most efficiently (STRING_SPLIT doesn't guarantee order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by "smart" guids, but why not just cast it to a char and pull out the parts by position?

```
create table t(myguid uniqueidentifier);
declare @p tinyint = 5;    
select      case @p
               when 1 then left(c.v, 8)
               when 2 then substring(c.v, 10, 4)
               when 3 then substring(c.v, 15, 4)
               when 4 then substring(c.v, 20, 4)
               when 5 then right(c.v, 12)
            end
from        t 
cross apply (select cast(t.myguid as char(36))) c(v)
```

Comment: Cheers mate! This is a simple yet great solution. I was messing around with charindex-es and it was getting out of hand. Thank you

Comment: Aww cmon, don't you love nesting `charindex` as much as I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use, OPENJSON

```
DECLARE @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'A7DDAA60-C33A-4D7A-A2D8-ABF20127C9AE', 
@s varchar(100)

Select @s = replace(@guid,'-','","')

Select * from
(
    Select [key] + 1 as Poistion, Value as Part
    FROM OPENJSON('["' +  @s + '"]')
) Q
Where Poistion in (2,4)
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=aea9ae86c50b5fe45e8b01663a2031a0).

Comment: Thank for this unique and interesting JSON based solution. Will definitely keep this in mind for future use cases. Cheers!